# ImageView.setImageBitmap(bla) function is not working on Android One Nougat 7.1.1

Tags: camera, imageview, photo, android-7.0-nougat

i have an app which takes photo then shows that on imageView, but the problem is on Android one or 7.1.1 Nougat phones do not shows the image on the screen, the other phones are working perfectly.(It works on Samsung S7 Edge Nougat 7.0.0 and also Nexus 5X Marshmallow 6.0.0 perfect.) Note : It is not crashes on 7.1.1, just doesn't shows and image on the screen.

Code sample after taking a photo :

```
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Show the thumbnail on ImageView
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
            try {
                InputStream ims = new FileInputStream(file);
                binding.ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the problem is that when I am trying to save file to directory it could not find a directory in External drive, the solution is, if you have no such a directory you need to create new one.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "AdoptPet/";
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            path), "Camera");
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```